# How to set a returned list from function into a record?

Tags: function, applescript, record

The following function returns a list - {1,2,3}

I want to enter each item of the list into a record with different values and keys.

Is there any easier way of doing this?

```
on somefunc()
    return {1, 2, 3}
end somefunc

set {a, b, c} to somefunc()
set my_record to {a:a, b:b, c:c}
```

This is what I basically want:

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with records, I like to use [ASObjC Runner](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner_vanilla.html)

Here is an example from the record suite:

```
tell application "ASObjC Runner" to link values {1, 2, 3} with labels {"a", "b", "c"}
```

EDIT

You can also use the run script method:

```
set myRecord to {}
set listA to {"a", "b", "c"}
set listB to {1, 2, 3}

repeat with i from 1 to count of listA
    set myRecord to myRecord & (run script "return {" & item i of listA & ":" & item i of listB & "}")
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use external programs.